# create mjpeg video from pictures in Android

Tags: android, image, video, mjpeg, boofcv

I have a small application that stream pictures from a device using android. I'm able to take pictures and save into sdcard and now I have been willing to do some video recording with that. I have done it using IOS: I save the pictures into an array and for each pictures, I create a mjpeg video with these combined pictures.

I have thought of using pure java to do so, but most of the import libraries cannot be supported in Android. 
I have tried to use this: https://github.com/lessthanoptimal/BoofCV/blob/master/main/io/src/boofcv/io/video/CreateMJpeg.java

But it cannot be played for some unknown reason.

I'm out of ideas. Please help me.

Thank you

Comment: have u solved ur problem?if yes then please share it to me this is a big issue for me..thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MJPEGGenerator.java](https://code.google.com/p/javadrone/source/browse/src/com/codeminders/ardrone/util/MJPEGGenerator.java) to create an AVI from a set of jpg images

[This is example](http://habrahabr.ru/post/172469/) of using MJPEGGenerator in russian language. Use translate.google.com to understand.